# why does the array elements change after block?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/6-frequency-finder)

> Given a sentence containing multiple words, find the frequency of a given word in that sentence.
>
> Construct a method named 'find_frequency' which accepts two arguments 'sentence' and 'word', both of which are String objects.
>
> **Example:** The method, given 'Ruby is The best language in the World' and 'the', should return 2 (comparison should be case-insensitive).
>
> **Hint:** You can use the method `Array#count` to count the frequency of any element in the given array.

Since the comparison should be case-insensitive. I use these code to help:

```
word = "the"
word_set = []
word.size.times do |i|
  word[i] = word[i].upcase
  word_set << word
  word[i] = word[i].downcase
end
```

Inside the block every time after `upcase` method the `word` does change and does add to the `word_set`, however when the block finish the `word_set` just contain `the the the`
What is the problem?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: If the sentence is `The tHe thE` and word is `the`, result should be `3`, so the code is try to get the set of every case of the word.

Comment: So you're trying to build every possible uppercase/lowercase combination of the word. Wouldn't it be easier to `downcase` both, the sentence and the word, so you can compare the downcased word against the downcased sentence?

Comment: Sure! This way is better, but I am still confused about that block code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am still confused about that block code

The block runs 3 times with `i = 0, 1, 2`. Here's what happens:

```
                               #  word   word_set
word[0] = word[0].upcase       #  'The'  []
word_set << word               #  'The'  ['The']
word[0] = word[0].downcase     #  'the'  ['the']

word[1] = word[1].upcase       #  'tHe'  ['tHe']
word_set << word               #  'tHe'  ['tHe', 'tHe']
word[1] = word[1].downcase     #  'the'  ['the', 'the']

word[2] = word[2].upcase       #  'thE'  ['thE', 'thE']
word_set << word               #  'thE'  ['thE', 'thE', 'thE']
word[2] = word[2].downcase     #  'the'  ['the', 'the', 'the']
```

This is because you are modifying the very same string object. At the end, your array contains the same string instance three times.

You can avoid this by using [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-dup) to create a *copy* of your string, something like:

```
word = "the"
word_set = []
word.size.times do |i|
  new_word = word.dup
  new_word[i] = new_word[i].upcase
  word_set << new_word
end

word_set #=> ["The", "tHe", "thE"]
```

Note that you still have to add `the`, `THe`, `tHE`, `ThE` and `THE` to your array.

Answer (score 1):

You add the same string to the array over and over again. In the end of the loop, the array will contain the same string n times (where n ist the length of the string). So, you are changing the same string back and forth between uppercase and lowercase, but it's still just one string.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Does this mean that I add the same `object #that string` n times? If so, how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `word[i] = word[i].upcase` is problematic, because you are setting it to upcase and downcase, the `word` will change over time. What you should have focused on is the Array#count method, which takes a block as a parameter.

Here is the gist of it:

```
def find_frequency sentence, word
  sentence.split(" ").count{|w| w == word }
end
```

To finish it off, complete the puzzle by taking into account case sensitivity of `word` and `sentence`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. By this way I can solve that probem. `sentence.split(" ").count{|w| w.downcase == word.downcase }
`  .But still how to avoid adding same string over time confused me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Array
  def group_and_count     
    self.map(&:downcase).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|k,h|h[k] += 1}
  end
end
```

Then when you want to find the frequency of a given word you could say:

```
> words = 'Here is a a a list OF OF words words WORDS'
> freq = words.split.group_and_count
> freq['a']
=> 3
```